# Get .csv from productCollection

Tags: database, sql, product-collection

I have the code below and I am wondering where to put this code/how to run it then to get a .csv file or .txt file at the end of the day.

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS.'var'.DS ;
$name ='sp1';
$file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csvdata = array();         

/* set Header  row*/
$headerRow = array(
        'sku',
        'mysku',
);
$csvdata[]=$headerRow;

/* add product data here */

 $productCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array(
       'like' => 'A%'));

     $productCollection->getSelect();   
    $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");
    $requestPathField = new Zend_Db_Expr($write->quoteIdentifier('sku'));
     $write->getSubstringSql($requestPathField,1);

    echo $productCollection->getSelect()->columns(array('mysku' =>  $write->getSubstringSql($requestPathField,1)));
    foreach($productCollection as $product):
    echo $product->getMysku().'<br/>';
    endforeach;


foreach($productCollection as &$product){
    $csvdata[]=array($product->getSku,$product->getMysku());
}

$csv->saveData($file , $csvdata);
```

**UPDATE**

So like this it would write my csv file?
My initial question was still where do I call it (where does this code stand) and where is the output. Will it be in media/export ?

Comment: ok i will check ..

Comment: thomas,it download at magentodir/var/sp1.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by `Varien_File_Csv` class which create csv.

**Please check**

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS.'var'.DS ;
$name ='sp1';
$file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csvdata = array();         

/* set Header  row*/
$headerRow = array(
        'sku',
        'mysku',
);
$csvdata[]=$headerRow;

/* add product data here */
foreach($productCollection as &$product){
    $csvdata[]=array($product->getSku,$product->getMysku());
}
$csv->saveData($file , $csvdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php  
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('./app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
 
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
getAllProducts($objectManager);

function getAllProducts($objectManager) {

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
// fputcsv($output, array('id', 'sku', 'description', 'title', 'meta_description'));

$header[]=array('id', 'sku','name');

    $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    $app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        $id=$product->getId();
        echo $id.PHP_EOL;
        $sku=$product->getSku();
        echo $sku.PHP_EOL;

        $name=$product->getName();

        echo $name.PHP_EOL;

        $header[]=array($id, $sku, $name);
    // fputcsv($output, array($id, $name));
    }
    $fp = fopen("getProducts.csv","w"); //first the read the file and header and create the data in csv
// $fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    foreach ($header as $line) {
        fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);      
}
?>
```